# combine directories into a virtual one

Tags: file, directory, virtual

in Windows XP
Does anybody know a software that maps multiple directories to ONE virtual drive or directory?

When I open the virtual directory, I want to see all files from mapped directories  as if it was one physical dir.

---

Linux software mhddfs seems to correspond exactly to my need.

from http://svn.uvw.ru/mhddfs/trunk/README

```
Consider we have two hard drives with the content below:

/hdd1             /hdd2
|                 |
+-- /dir1         +-- /dir1
|   |             |   |
|   +- file2      |   +- file4
|                 |   +- file2
+-- file1         |
|                 +-- file5
+-- /dir2         |
    |             +-- /dir3
    +- file3          |
                      +- file6

mounting this tree with the command:

mhddfs /hdd1,/hdd2 /hdd_common

into the specified file system point we will see a combined tree.

In the united tree we can see all the directories and files. Note
file2 of 2nd hdd is not visible (because 1st hdd  has  the  file2
already).

/hdd_common
|
+-- /dir1
|   |
|   +-- file2  -> /hdd1/dir1/file2
|   +-- file4
|
|-- /dir2
|   |
|   + file3
|
+-- /dir3
|   |
|   +-- file6
|
+-- file1
+-- file5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite the solution you want, but if you can live with all source directories having their own sub directory in a new target, you can check out the Windows tool [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) from the Sysinternals Suite.

It allows you to create and manage symbolic links. your tree structure would be something like:

```
E:\hdd_common
├───hdd1
│   └───some folder structure [...]
└───hdd2
    └───some other folder structure [...]
```

Call it like:

```
junction "e:\hdd_common\hdd1" "f:\"
junction "e:\hdd_common\hdd2" "g:\"
```